# Gulp check if webp image exists before converting

Tags: gulp, webp

I am using gulp to iterate through my image directories and create a webp version of each of the images contained.

This works perfectly well but every time I run the build process it reconverts every image.

How can I get the function to check if a webp version of each file already exists before converting?

```
    gulp.task('convert-webp', function () {
       return gulp.src('media/image/**/*')
          .pipe(webp())
          .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
             return file.base;
          }));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gulp package [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) or probably others to test each file in the pipeline:

```js
const gulpIF = require('gulp-if');

gulp.task('convert-webp', function () {
  return gulp.src('media/image/**/*')

       // use below for testing purposes
      .pipe(gulpIF("!**/*.webp", webp(), gulp.dest('onyWebp')))

      // use this version when satisfied it is working
      // .pipe(gulpIF("!**/*.webp", webp()))

    .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
      return file.base;
    }));
});
```

`gulpIF("!**/*.webp", webp(), gulp.dest('onyWebp'))`

The above will test if the current file is **not** a `.webp` file, if it is not (so the condition is true) those files will go to `webp()`, all other files (i.e., the `.webp` files) will go to the `onlyWebp` directory.  So you can see that those files are not going through the `webp()` pipe.

All files still go to the final `gulp.dest`.

They are other ways to set up the condition, like:

```
"!**/*.{png,jpg,bmp,jpeg,jpeg2,webp,svg}"   // exclude these
"*.{png,jpg}"                               // include these
```